# Removing portion between two \n when a specific sub-string is there [PHP]

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I have a variable in which I store some HTML code.
Let's say:

```
<div> 
<span> test of {my_string} </span> 
{my_string} 
test of {my_string} 
</div> 
<h1> {my_string} </h1>
```

I would need to remove some lines containing a specific value so the end result looks like:

```
<div>
</div>
```

So I was thinking of getting the position of the string with `strpos` and then get the `\n` which are before and after. But how can I search backwards with `strpos` as I already have an offset specified?

```
$rep_pos = strpos($message, 'my_string');
$line_begining = ????
$line_end = strpos($message, '\n', $rep_pos);
```

I can't use `strip_tags` because I don't know in advance what will be the tags around and some other strings can use the same tags.

Comment: check this, http://www.onlinecode.org/remove-html-tags-string-using-php/

Comment: no, I don't want to use strip_tags as I don't know in advance which tags will be used around the string

Comment: use **preg_replace**

Comment: Thanks: $message = preg_replace("/my_string/i", "", $message); But how do I catch both \n ?

Comment: check this https://3v4l.org/ON5mR , it will help you.

Comment: Thanks but you are catching the tags here. I need to catch the carriage return as the begining of the line would not mandatory be a tag

Comment: @VincentTeyssier what result do you want if it will be `<div>
  <p> <span> my_string </span> </p>
</div>` ? Do you want to remove just one level or up to body?

Comment: I'm editing to put a more all cases example

Comment: Judging by your example, you speak about text lines but not about HTML elements. Because in second case div should ne removed - it contains your string.

Comment: yes, text lines (but not in a file, stored in a variable)

Comment: explode it to array and use array_filter or usual loop to remove lines with a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DOMDocument` for parsing HTML tags string. Here we are using `XPath query` which is `//*[text()=" my_string "]` which means get all elements which contains `my_string` text.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785554)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string='<html>
           <body>
             <div>
               <span> my_string </span>
             </div>
             <h1> my_string </h1>
           </body>
         </html>';
$domobject= new DOMDocument();
$domobject->loadHTML($string);
$xpath= new DOMXPath($domobject);
$result=$xpath->query('//*[text()=" my_string "]');
Foreach($result as $nodes)
{
    $nodes->parentNode->removeChild($nodes);
}
echo $domobject->saveHTML();
```

**Solution 2:**

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/C3gxyS/8/)

Comment: Thanks, that's very elegant and prove reliable :)

Comment: Voted up and will accept tomorrow in case a better answer comes up ;)

Comment: Dave suggested a regex, that might perform better on a production server with high volume of requests

Comment: @VincentTeyssier Regex is not a good solution for handling HTML string but if you think so , then that would not be a good approach, But if you choose regex try this https://regex101.com/r/C3gxyS/1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143205/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-vincent-teyssier).